# Switch Case with Radio Button - C#

Tags: c#, radio-button, switch-statement

I'm trying to develop a switch case statement that allows me to run code based depending on what of the 3 radio buttons I have are selected.  I have a message box statement to tell me if this was successful, but it never shows so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

Any advice would be great

```
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton();
        if (radioBtn.Enabled == true)
        {
            switch (radioBtn.Name)
            {
                case "radioButton1":
                    ComicBooks CB = new ComicBooks();
                    CB.setTitle(textBox1.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show(CB.Title);
                    break;

                case "radioButton2":
                    //do something
                    break;

                case "radioButton3":
                    //do something
                    break;

            } 

        }
```

Comment: `RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton)sender;`

Comment: You are creating a new `RadioButton` without name,so of course it does nothing

Comment: No @JohnnyMopp. This seems to be a Button Click event, so you are not going to be able to cast sender to RadioButton

Comment: @Pikoh I don't follow you.  That name is radioBtn

Comment: @Justin you're creating a new instance of a `RadioButton`, you're not calling the instance on your UI. You need to use something like this.radioBtn.Name, and remove the instantiation at top.

Comment: @Pikoh You may be right. Would need OP to clarify.

Comment: In cases like these it is easy to debug the code. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p4.html By using breakpoints you can get a better understanding of what is happening and what isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are creating a new instance of `RadioButton` here:

```
RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton();
```

This instance is not connected to anything in your UI, and has no `Name` property setted, so it does not match any `switch`case.

If you want to check what `RadioButton` is selected when you click a button, and do something depending of its name, you can do this:

```
RadioButton radioBtn = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                       .Where(x=>x.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
if (radioBtn!=null)
{
    switch (radioBtn.Name)
    {
        case "radioButton1":
           //Your switch structure here ...

}
```

If the `RadioButtons` are not in the Form itself, but for example in a Panel, you'll need to change the first line of my code for this:

```
RadioButton radioBtn = this.panel1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                           .Where(x=>x.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
```

Notice `this.panel1.Controls` part

Comment: `var name = this.panel1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked)?.Name;` would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you are creating a brand new RadioButton object and creating a reference to it named radioBtn.

```
RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton();
```

So, in your switch statement, none of your blocks are being entered because radioBtn.Name is going to be null, or some default value assigned by the .net framework.

Instead of creating a new RadioButton, you probably want to check the values of existing RadioButtons that you added via the Visual Studio graphical designer.  So your code would look something like below (with made-up names, because I don't know what you named your actual RadioButtons in the designer):

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (radioButton1.Checked)
  { 
    ComicBooks CB = new ComicBooks();
    CB.setTitle(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(CB.Title);
  }
  else if (radioButton2.Checked)
  { 
    // do something
  }
  else if (radioButton3.Checked)
  { 
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I was told that a switch case statement would be better for this instead of if statements.  Looks like you can go either way

Comment: @Justin switch is fine for this too, but the logic in this answer applies to any control structures you employ.